# Reason for NumberFormat Exception(converting String to long)

Tags: java

Friend's,
      I'm trying to convert an string into long type,here i'm getting NumberFormat Exception,how can i fix this problem.

Comment: ugh... by fixing your string? Today is the day of funny questions.

Comment: The cause of this exception Is either passing character,string instead of numbers as string or empty string

Comment: What is the string that is causing the problem? Can you post a code snippet that reproduces the exception?

Comment: -1 for not posting your code or your exception stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

I think you've used

```
Long.parseLong(String s)
```

or

```
String String.valueOf(long l)
```

so your string just doesn't contain a long number. That's it.